# Isometric isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

In the case that $L:B_1 \rightarrow B_2 $ is a linear mapping of Banach spaces and $L$ is a isometric isomorphism  (bijection and $\|Lx\|_{B_1} = \|x\|_{B_2} $)  can I say that $L\overline{L}= 1 $ is trivial ? (the bar denotes the complex conjugate);

TIA

Comment: I don't think so, but before I can be sure, I must ask how the complex conjugate of $L$ is defined?

Comment: So $\overline{L}$ is defined as $\overline{L}(\alpha x+\beta y)=\overline{\alpha}L(x)+\overline{\beta}L(y)$. Right?

Comment: What is meant by $L\overline{L}$? Is there a multiplication operation on $B_2$?

Comment: Is there a confusion here with the adjoint of an isometry between Hilbert spaces? For which $LL^*=1$? That particular result has no generalization to Banach spaces that I know of.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It is worth to mention that this equality makes no sense for Bancach spaces.

Comment: I try to show that if $L$ is a isomorphism of Banach so $L$ is a isomorphism of Hilbert in the case that $B_1 ,B_2 $ spaces are Hilbert so $\langle x,y\rangle  =  \langle Lx,Ly\rangle $. by using rules of inner product I finally get  $\langle x,y\rangle =L\overline{L} \langle x,y\rangle $

Comment: I guess it is just the same as Harald mentioned, and $\bar L$ wants to mean the *adjoint* of $L$.

Answer (score 1):

I am going out on a limb to answer a different question – but possibly the question that was intended, if the comments are anything to go by:

Assume $L\colon H_1\to H_2$ is a linear isometry *between Hilbert spaces*. Then using the polarization identity
$$ \langle x,y\rangle=\frac14\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k\lVert x+i^ky\rVert^2 $$
we can deduce $\langle Lx,Ly\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x$ and $y$, so that $L^*L=I_1$ (where $I_1$ is the identity on $H_1$). Since $L$ is also assumed to be a bijection, $LL^*=I_2$ follows, where $I_2$ is the identity on $H_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is true.

As an example take $B_1 = B_2 = \mathbb{C}^3$ equipped with euclidean norm. Choose a basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3 \}$ of $\mathbb{C}^3$ and define $L = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Note that $L$ permutes the coordinates of $\mathbb{C}^3$ and $L^3 = 1$. Hence $L$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Assuming $\overline{L}(\alpha x + \beta y) := \overline{\alpha}L(x)+ \overline{\beta}L(y)$ we have $\forall \ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ :

$L \circ \overline{L} (\lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + \lambda_3 e_3) = \overline{\lambda_1} e_3 + \overline{\lambda_2} e_1 + \overline{\lambda_3} e_2 $

which in general is $\neq \lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + \lambda_3 e_3$.